# Cluster job management in R via future package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future

I want to use the `R` package `future` (supports asynchronous calculations) to make a cluster-jobserver that can dynamically add/remove jobs to/from a queue.

One specific functionality that I would like to add to my jobserver is to distribute memory-demanding jobs to the more powerful machines in my cluster. However, since I have no experience with the package, I am not quite sure whether my approach (given below) has any pitfalls. Specifically, do the subsequent calls of `plan` have any side effects that might mess things up? Please see the comments in the code for more details.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(parallel)
library(future)

slaveIPs=c("172.16.2.10","172.16.2.21")
masterIP="172.16.2.33"
workers=makePSOCKcluster(slaveIPs,master=masterIP)

#check whether PSOCK cluster was correctly set up
unlist(clusterCall(workers,function(x) unname(Sys.info()["nodename"]))
#[1] "ip-172-16-2-10" "ip-172-16-2-21"

#now the first important part that I am not sure about
#as you can see, I only use workers[1] for the first task
#is it OK to use workers[1] like that?
plan(cluster,workers=workers[1])

f=future({
  #do memory-hungry work
  unname(Sys.info()["nodename"])
})

message(value(f))
#ip-172-16-2-10

#now I am only using workers[2] for the second task
#Is this ok? Does the previous call to 'plan' need some cleaning before?
plan(cluster,workers=workers[2])

f=future({
  #do low-memory work
  unname(Sys.info()["nodename"])
})

message(value(f))
#ip-172-16-2-21

stopCluster(workers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) here:

Yes, it alright to change future strategies like that, i.e. by using `plan()`.  An alternative is to use:

```
f <- cluster({
  #do low-memory work
  unname(Sys.info()["nodename"])
}, workers = workers[2])
```

which is basically what is happening internally.

The downside of explicitly specifying future strategies like this is that your code will be hard coded to use `cluster` futures.

FYI, I'm planning to add some kind of mechanism for specifying preferred or required "resources" per future.  This is just conceptual for now and will not exists anytime soon, but I'm thinking of something in line with:

```
f <- future({ ... }, needs = "himem")
```

where one can query workers for the `himem` tag / property, e.g. `attr(workers[2], "provides") <- c("himem", "superfast")`.  I'm sharing these thoughts just so you know that I'm aware of needs like yours.  Again, it will be quite some time before such mechanisms are available, so in the meanwhile, you need to explicitly specify the future strategy as above.

BTW, instead of:

```
slaveIPs=c("172.16.2.10","172.16.2.21")
masterIP="172.16.2.33"
workers=makePSOCKcluster(slaveIPs,master=masterIP)
```

you can try:

```
slaveIPs <- c("172.16.2.10", "172.16.2.21")
workers <- makeClusterPSOCK(slaveIPs)
```

provided by the `future` package - this avoids having to know/specify the IP address of master.

Comment: Oh, great! Thx for your help and the great(!) package.